# Using Query in Razor to sort tables

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My goal is to generate a table per object in the db, say in my case cars. Depending on the condition of the car I then want to display information in a given table of that given car. My problem is that I am currently displaying the same information in every table about every car, Independent of a car.

Is there a way to perform queries in Razor? I know the Id of my current car, and that way I could query the information that is necescary. Here is my current code:

```
@foreach (var car in Model.myCars)
{



   <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.CarName)</h5>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Sjekkpunkt</th>
                <th>Avviksbeskrivelse</th>
                <th>Risiko</th>
                <th>Dato rapportert</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        @foreach (var item in Model.myCheckpoints.Zip(Model.myAnswers, (Item1, Item2) => new { Item1, Item2 }))
        {


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item1.Id)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item1.Description)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item2.Deviation)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item2.Risk)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item2.dateReported)</td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Problem with this code that for every car i iterate the exact same information is displayed. Now there is an connection between the Car table and Model.myCheckpoints. Is there any way to query so that it is possible to only myCheckpoints connected to the given car at a given iteration is displayed?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you perform this sort of logic in the controller, rather than the view. While it is certainly possible to do so in the view, it is not a best practice. What you want to do is to filter your collections in the controller so as to provide your view with a specific model object that contains what you need to display, thereby allowing you to keep the logic to a minimum (if any at all) in the view. What you need to investigate is using a function such as LINQ's `Where` that will allow you to perform this filtering.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all to answer to your questions:**

**1.    Is there a way to perform queries in Razor?**

I strongly recommend not to perform the query operation in razor , even though there is a way  for it.
Perform all your query logic in the controller or separate helper files and pass only the result of the query to the view.

**2.Is there any way to query so that it is possible to only myCheckpoints connected to the given car at a given iteration is displayed?**

You can do whatever queries as per requirement using the linq functions.
Ex:
var Result = anyList.Where(s => s.Anycolumn1 > 12).Where(s => s. Anycolumn2 < 20);

**Note :** In yourcase if you know the id of the car  , then filter it using the id column.

Hope the above information was useful, kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks
Karthik